# How to scroll down to top, but not instantaneously?

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events

I'm using

```
 window.scrollTo('#body')
```

for scrolling to the top of the page but its quite instantaneous and looks odd.
So, I wanted a function which scrolls to the top after a button click at bottom but not instantaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery's animate would be the most straight forward way to do it. But in case, you want to stick to pure JS, you can do:

```
function scrollUp() {
  window.scrollBy(0, -10); // change this '10' as needed to control the smoothness of the scroll
  if(window.pageYOffset > 0) setTimeout(scrollUp, 10);
}

scrollUp();
```

Answer (score 1):

why dont you use jquery

$('body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 });

Comment: Bhuhan
I never use jquery can you tell me how to use it.

Comment: just include 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
in the head tag and then include the code i gave in a seperate script tag

Comment: jquery is a very nice library for doing more and writing less. does the work of large javascript in a few lines of code

Answer (score 1):

Did something similar couple days ago and searched quite some time for an easy, yet tweeked solution:

The code is part from a .net project but since you tagged javascript-events I thought I'd paste it as well. It runs after an update panel.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    prm.add_endRequest(resetPosition);

    function resetPosition() {
        //prm._scrollPosition.y = 0;
        //window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        //$(window).scrollTop();
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 100);
    }
// ]]>
</script>
```

So for the button click:

```
$(function(){
    $("#myButton").click(function(){
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 200);
    });
});
```